# Does $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1\dfrac{dx}{nx}$ converge to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis

I was asked to construct a sequence of continuous functions which converge pointwise to zero on the interval $[0,1]$, but whose $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n(x)dx$ does not converge to $0$.

So, I constructed the sequence $f_n(x) = \dfrac{1}{nx}$, but I am not sure how to take this limit.

Comment: These are not functions on [0,1], unless you explain what $f_n(0)$ should be (and then the result will not be continuous).

Comment: I assume you should rather have that $\int_0^1 f_n(x)\,\mathrm dx$ exists (is finite) for all $n$ in the first place. This will of course be the case if you really make $f_n$ continuous.

Answer (score 5):

The integral
$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x}$$
is divergent so your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The only way for this question to make any sense is to replace the lower integration limit $0$ with a function of *n*, in which case it would depend on how fast this $f(n)$ approaches $0$, as opposed to the speed of *n* itself as it tends to $\infty$. For instance,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\tfrac1n^1\frac{dx}{nx}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n}n=0,$$

and generally, for a positive *k* and nonzero *a*,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{(an)^{-k}}^1\frac{dx}{nx}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{k\ln(an)}n=0,$$

but, at the same time,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{n^{-n}}^1\frac{dx}{nx}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\ln n}n=\infty\neq0.$$

Comment: "The only way for this question to make any sense is to replace the lower integration limit 0 with a function of n" No, not the only way.

Answer (score 0):

> I was asked to construct a sequence of continuous functions which converge pointwise to zero on the interval $[0,1]$, but [such that] $\int_0^1f_n(x)\mathrm dx$ does not converge to $0$.

Try the functions $f_n(x)=n^\color{red}{\alpha}x^n(1-x)$ for various values of the parameter $\color{red}{\alpha}$.